# Regex pattern only catches first occurrence of US address

Tags: python, regex

I have a transcribed text where customer and agent talks to each other. I want to match addresses. I have a regex pattern:

```py
\d+ (.)?(dr|drive|circle|highway|way|street|st|road|rd|boulevard|blvd|parkway|avenue|ave\b|court|ct|cove\b|crossing|estate|junction|loop|park|\bpike\b|ridge|square|terrace|trail|turnpike|village) .*? \d{4,6}
```

It catches the address. However, it does not catch second address. How to catch all addresses instead of only first occurrence? The second address is appended to end of the sample text `15620 e glenwood...` I provide my pattern and sample text below:

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/2TZqkb/1)

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match street names beginning with the word `e`.

Comment: I don't understand your regexp. You have the type of road right after the number, without allowing for the name of the road in between. The only reason it matches the first address is because the street name begins with `circle`, which is also one of the road types.

Comment: I think you want `.*?` *before* the list of road types, not after. Maybe `(.)?` was supposed to be `(.*?)`?

Comment: But it shouldn't be the algorithm is this (some digits) then (avenue road circle ...) then again (some digits)

Comment: `15620 e glenwood` doesn't fit that pattern since you don't have `(avenue road circle)` after the digits.

Comment: I see. I just redacted the remaining to keep it short in the question. If you click regex101 link the full address is `15620 e glenwood road 80016`. Thanks.

Comment: I know, I looked at regex101 when I first read the question. The regex doesn't have `e` in the list `(avenue|road|circle|...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added to your original regex `( \w+ )?` at the begining to iclude the case where the user says the name of the road

this should do the trick :

```
\d+ (.)?( \w+ )?(dr|drive|circle|highway|way|street|st|road|rd|boulevard|blvd|parkway|avenue|ave\b|court|ct|cove\b|crossing|estate|junction|loop|park|\bpike\b|ridge|square|terrace|trail|turnpike|village).*?\d{4,6}
```